# tbb::parallel_reduce vs tbb::combinable vs tbb::enumerable_thread_specific

Tags: c++, multithreading, image-processing, tbb, eigen3

I want to go through an image and process some specific values with regard to the **order** of the elements. The image has one `unsigned char*` array containing a mask(255 if pixel should be processed, else 0) and an `unsigned short*` array with the pixel values.

I implemented three different methods with tbb and used a single for-loop through the mask-array and calculated the x,y-coordinates from the loop-variable:  `x = i%width; y = i/width;`. If the pixel is visible i want to transform the point using `Eigen`.
The `vector4d` is a `std::vector<std::array<double,4>>` to store the points.

Here are my three implementaion with tbb:

**1. `tbb::combinable` and `tbb::parallel_for` :**

```
void Combinable(int width, int height, unsigned char* mask,unsigned short*  pixel){ 
    MyCombinableType.clear();
    MyCombinableType.local().reserve(width*height);
    tbb::parallel_for( tbb::blocked_range<int>(0, width*height),
        [&](const tbb::blocked_range<int> &r) 
    {       
        vector4d& local = MyCombinableType.local(); 
        const size_t end = r.end(); 
        for (int i = r.begin(); i != end; ++i)
        {
            if(mask[i]!=0)
            {                                       
                array4d arr = {i%width,i/width,(double)pixel[i],1}; 
                //Map with Eigen and transform
                local.push_back(arr);           
            }
        }
    });

    vector4d idx = MyCombinableType.combine(
        []( vector4d x, vector4d y) 
    {               
        std::size_t n = x.size();
        x.resize(n + y.size());
        std::move(y.begin(), y.end(), x.begin() + n);
        return x;
    });
}
```

**2. `tbb::enumerable_thread_specific` and `tbb::parallel_for`:**

```
void Enumerable(int width, int height, unsigned char* mask,unsigned short*  pixel){
    MyEnumerableType.clear();
    MyEnumerableType.local().reserve(width*height);
    tbb::parallel_for( tbb::blocked_range<int>(0, width*height),
        [&](const tbb::blocked_range<int> &r) 
    {
        enumerableType::reference local = MyEnumerableType.local();
        for (int i = r.begin(); i != r.end(); ++i)
        {
            if(mask[i]!=0)
            {
                array4d arr = {i%width,i/width,(double)pixel[i],1}; 
                //Map with Eigen and transform
                local.push_back(arr);               

            }
        }
    });

    vector4d idx = MyEnumerableType.combine(
        [](vector4d x, vector4d y) 
    {           
        std::size_t n = x.size();
        x.resize(n + y.size());
        std::move(y.begin(), y.end(), x.begin() + n);
        return x;
    });
}
```

**3. `tbb::parallel_reduce`:**

```
void Reduce(int width, int height, unsigned char* mask,unsigned short*  pixel){
    vector4d idx = tbb::parallel_reduce(
        tbb::blocked_range<int>(0, width*height ),vector4d(),
            [&](const tbb::blocked_range<int>& r, vector4d init)->vector4d 
        {
            const size_t end = r.end(); 
            init.reserve(r.size());
            for( int i=r.begin(); i!=end; ++i )
            {   
                if(mask[i]!=0)
                {               
                    array4d arr = {i%width,i/width,(double)pixel[i],1}; 
                    //Map with Eigen and transform
                    init.push_back(arr);            
                }
            }
            return init;
        },
        []( vector4d x,vector4d y )
        {
            std::size_t n = x.size();
            x.resize(n + y.size());
            std::move(y.begin(), y.end(), x.begin() + n);           
            return x;
        }
    );  
}
```

I compared the runtime of the three versions with a serial implementation. The arrays had 8400000 elements and every algortihm was repeated 100 times. The results are:

- Serial: ~170ms
- Enumerable: ~118ms
- Combinable: ~116ms
- Reduce: ~720ms

I assume that the `combine` statement is the bottleneck here. What am i doing wrong? Why is `parallel_reduce` soo much slower? Please help!

Comment: You're passing `vector4d` by value to the lambda expression.  How expensive is the copy constructor for `vector4d`?

Comment: I updated my question. I totally forgot to mention vector4d, thanks for the hint!

Comment: see my better answer below, but a minor improvement to your code would be: `init.reserve(init.size() + r.size());`

Answer (score 1):

There are few optimizations you can apply here.

1. avoid excessive copying: pass `const vector4d&` instead, use `[&]` lambdas everywhere.
2. Use temporary `vector4d` on stack instead of resizing one of the arguments and use it for return statement.
3. Generally, use `blocked_range2d` instead of calculating `x = i%width; y = i/width`. This is not only optimizes out excessive computations but, which is much more important, it optimizes cache access pattern that might improve cache usage (not in this case though).

Answer (score 0):

You are using the functional form of parallel_reduce, try the more efficient imperative form instead. Unfortunately it cannot be called using lambdas, you must define a Body class:

https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/algorithms/parallel_reduce_func.html

It should minimize the number vector4d copies that are made during your reduction. The vector4d should be a member of your Body class so that it can be reused and appended to by multiple ranges, rather than constructing and merging a unique vector4d for every subdivided range.

(Note: the splitting constructor should NOT copy the contents of the vector4d member, notice how `value` is always initialized to 0 in intel's example above.)